# draw(Canvas canvas) method running twice in application

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

First do look on my code.

Here's my code:-

```
public GameView(Context context){ 
super(context);

Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(
             Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
}

@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int imageWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = bmp.getHeight();

        int width = display.getWidth();
        System.out.println("Width = " +width);
        int height = display.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Height = " +height);
        Random randomX,randomY;
        randomX = new Random();
        randomY = new Random();

        x = randomX.nextInt(width - imageWidth);
        System.out.println("X = " +x);
        y = randomY.nextInt(height - imageHeight);
        System.out.println("Y = " +y);

        Rect dst = new Rect(x , y , x + imageWidth , y + imageHeight);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null , dst , null);
        System.out.println("dst = " +dst);


        super.draw(canvas);
    }
```

My code is running perfectly but my problem is that the `draw(Canvas canvas)` running twice.
Here's logs which i am getting them in Logcat every time with different values:-

```
Width=480
Height=800
X=247
Y=456
dst = Rect(247 , 456 - 319 , 528) 
Width=480
Height=800
X=119
Y=560
dst = Rect(119 , 560 - 191 , 632)
```

Every time when I am running my application,draw(Canvas canvas) is running twice.I dont want that it'll run twice every time.Help me to get rid of this problem.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you override any method,better call

```
 super.overridedMethod();
```

first,then code your implementation.

Try,

```
 super.draw();
 //NOW YOUR STUFF
```

or remove `super.draw();`

### Update

You better override `onDraw()` method than `draw()`.

### Again update

Make sure that `setContentView(new GameView(this));` is called in `onCreate()`.

Hope this may help you

Comment: No buddy not helpful in my case,still draw(Canvas canvas) is running twice every time when i run my app.

Comment: I have just created a Main activity and pass the GameView constructor in setContentView()( e. g. setContentView(new GameView(this));) and I have already pasted the code which i have put in GameView.

Comment: I tried your code,but mine is working **only once**.. Was it on onCreate() or anyother method???

Comment: did you run the code only once or more then once.Becoz i am not getting this problem to run at first time, but after that every time i am getting the double values.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036665/the-ondraw-method-in-my-surfaceview-is-called-twice pablo also asking about the same question but nobody answered him.

Comment: No i am always getting only `once`. you did write it in  onCreate(),did n't you???

Comment: you are right it will run only at once in onCreate() but i dont want to run my code in on onCreate because i am going to extend my code and trying to make an useful app and i know ur approach will give me more big problems in near future in my app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6601/discussion-between-sonu-thomas-and-himanshu)